# WordPress pods pagination not taking limit parameter

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

I’m new using the pods plugin so maybe it’s a misuse of the pagination function.

I have a simple code where I call in a custom template page a pods taxonomy, I list them and then I put the pagination. In my request I put a limit of 20 object by request, as I understand it, this parameter should be passed on to the pagination function and the display should be of 20 entries by page.

Or when navigating , I have a random number of entries depdending on the letter I’m trying to display (9,14,12,10).

I would like to be able to lock it at 20 if possible, could you help me finding what I'm doing wrong?

The code in question:

```
if(isset($_GET["let"])){
    $let = $_GET["let"];
    $params = array( 
        "limit"   =>  20,  // -1 Return all rows 
        "where" => "t.name LIKE '".$let."%'"
    );
}else{
    $let = "all";
    $params = array( 
        'limit'   =>  20  // -1 Return all rows 
    );
}
$adherents = pods("adherent",$params);

echo "<div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-5' id='cibe-adherent-title'>
            <h1>Nos Adhérents</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' id='cibe-annuaire-tri'>
        <div class='col-lg-12 text-lg-center'>
            <a href='".get_permalink()."'";
            if($let == "all") echo " class='cibe-active-link'";
            echo        ">Tous</a> ";

            for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
                echo "<a href='".get_permalink()."/annuaire-des-adherents/?let=".chr($i)."'";
                if($let == chr($i)) echo " class='cibe-active-link'";
                echo ">".chr($i)."</a> ";
            }

    echo "      </div>
            </div>";

    while($adherents->fetch()){
        $current_url = add_query_arg('term_id', $adherents->field("term_id"), get_permalink());
        if($adherents->field("adherent") == 1)
            echo "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-11 offset-lg-1'>
                        <a href='".$current_url."'>".$adherents->field("name")."</a>
                    </div>
                </div>";
    }

    echo "<div class='row' id='cibe-annuaire-pagination'>
            <div class='col-lg-12 text-lg-center'>
                ".$adherents->pagination()."
            </div>
        </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my post, it may be a misuse, and it is! Thinking on my code, I have this condition
 `if($adherents->field("adherent") == 1)`

That is why some are not displaying.

I did this at the beginning when I didn't know you could use where condition in the pods parameters.

If I correct this it should work.